# How create a siddhi app with Multiple conditional count

Tags: window, aggregation, siddhi

I have a special situation and I can not implement it with siddhi options like window, pattern or aggregation  functions. The data comes from 2 streams, I set the source in both streams of KAFKA and I set the list of topics in siddhi source p1, p2. I wrote a query for checks 2 rules (type = "h") and (type = "g"). The siddhi app must only allows events to match these conditions. I need to aggregate every 10 seconds, when the number of events that match the first condition is 2 and the number of events that match the second condition is 5 at this time. How?

Comment: I found this solution that siddhi support, exactly what i need, but the output of this solution is wrong:                                                                                                                              from stream1#window.timeBatch(10 seconds)
 select type, id, count(type == 'h') as cnt1, count(type == 'g') as cnt2
  having cnt1 == 2 and cnt2 == 5
 insert all events into stream2;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

```
from stream1#window.time(10 seconds)
select type, id, sum(ifThenElse(type == 'h', 1, 0)) as cnt1,   sum(ifThenElse(type == 'g', 1, 0)) as cnt2
    having cnt1 == 2 and cnt2 == 5
insert all events into stream2;
```

I tested this code manytimes with many values(0, 1, 2, ...) that passed all of them.